# URLClassloader Dependencies

Tags: java, class, loading

In my previous question, I asked how to load remote jar files. My current code is this:

```
//f is the path to the jar
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{f.toURI().toURL()});
Class<?> jarClass = Class.forName(main, true, loader);
Class<? extends Module> module = jarClass.asSubclass(Module.class);

Constructor<? extends Module> constructor = module.getConstructor();
System.out.println(constructor);

Module module = constructor.newInstance();
```

This works well, but the remotely-loaded modules extend a class that is in the jar that is loading them, which gives this error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package.whatever.Module, which I presume is because it is using URLClassLoader instead of getClass().getClassLoader().. how can I make it use URLClassLoader and then fall back to the default one?

Thanks, 
Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your application class loader to be the parent of the url class loader:

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(
       new URL[]{f.toURI().toURL()}, Module.class.getClassLoader());
```

From the [Oracle Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html) (class loading mechanism):

> The Java platform uses a delegation model for loading classes. The
>   basic idea is that every class loader has a "parent" class loader.
>   When loading a class, a class loader first "delegates" the search for
>   the class to its parent class loader before attempting to find the
>   class itself.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I was using Java 9, downgrading back it to Java 8 resolved my issue.